# Hadoop job execution if not space in the cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing

Is there any way to run the hadoop job on cluster if there is no space in the cluster. need to run without free the data from cluster.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If there is no space on the cluster, where will the platform be able to compute? You are aware that it uses lots of temporary files and directories when it compute?

Comment: The question is phrased in such a way that it is impossible to answer. You simply must free up space in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can free the space by changing the replication factor on hadoop cluster. After executing the job we can restore to previous replication factor.

Thanks